# Changes to my Twitter design aren't persisting

Tags: twitter

For the longest time I have had a background image on my Twitter design:

[image]

However recently I have had just a plain off white background:

[image]

I have tried just resetting the design and changing the background and initially it seems to take, but then reverts to off white.

What's changed and why can't I change the background any more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter removed backgrounds, I assume either to emphasise more user focus to ads or something else entirely.

> We’re removing background images from the home and notifications timelines on web for all users. Now, background images are only available where logged-in users will see them publicly (Tweet pages, list pages and collections pages). You can find help center content about customizing your design and where it’s visible on Twitter

source: http://thenextweb.com/twitter/2015/07/21/twitter-is-removing-backgrounds-from-user-profiles/

- Profile page - no https://twitter.com/phwd/
- Tweet Page - yes https://twitter.com/phwd/status/621037631657410560
- List Page - yes  https://twitter.com/phwd/lists/inception
- Collection page - yes https://twitter.com/phwd/timelines/628319002666868736

Comment: So a) why do I see the image (albeit temporarily) at all?, and b) why do I see other users images on their profiles but not mine?

Comment: Actually, I might have been mistaken about seeing background images on other's profile pages - hence my confusion.